# Calculus spivak question chapter 11, ex 63,b

Tags: calculus

If $g(x)=x^2 sin(1/x)$ show that there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to 0 with $g'(x)=1$ and also $g'(x)=-1$.

I saw the solutions book, but i don't understand, it just shows the derivative ]
$$g'(x)=2xsin(1/x)-cos(1/x)$$

and says $g'(x)=-1$ if $cos(1/x)=-1$ and $sin(1/x)=0$. Can some one help me with that please. Thank you

Comment: They made a sign error. If $\cos (1/x) = -1$, then $g'(x) = +1$. Other than that, what would you like to have explained?

Comment: For $1/x =\ell \pi$, $\sin(1/x)=0$ and $\cos(1/x)=(-1)^\ell$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for your answer, my problem was what values of $x$ to take, it became more clear with Dr's value.